# How to use multiple models in one controller

Tags: laravel, model, controller

I have six models that I need to get in one instance in my controller. How can I do that?

I have my six models:

```
CommentaireCritique
CommentaireNews
CommentaireDossier
CommentaireEpisode
CommentaireSerie
CommentaireTrailer
```

They all have the same structure in my database, and I would like to show the latest comms on one single page. I don't know if it's possible to bind them in a single controller. I tried that, but it's not working.

```php
public function index()
{
    $comms = CommentaireCritique::all() && CommentaireNews::all()
        && CommentaireDossier::all() && CommentaireEpisode::all()
        && CommentaireSerie::all() && CommentaireTrailer::all()
            ->get();

    return view('admin.commentaires.index', compact('comms'));
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using one Commentaire model with a polymorphic relation?

Comment: I don't know how I can do that. I'm gonna make a quick search. It is the best way to do it for you ?

Comment: If all your Commentaire models are the same (except for the foreign key of the model they comment on), then yes. Polymorphic relation basically means you have two columns that describe the foreign reference instead of one. Your `CommentaireEpisode` model may now have a `episode_id` reference. A polymorphic `Commentaire` model would have a column `commentable_id` that replaces this column and a `commentable_type` which contains the type of referenced model, which would be `App\Episode` in your example (or `App\Models\Episode` if you use another namespace for example).

Comment: I already have a database set up. I work on a new version of an existing website. If I understand correctly I would need to rearrange my database. I don't know if I'm gonna make a new database, I don't know how to import all my data..

Answer (score 0):

just after the namespace , before the class declaration

```
use yourAppNameSpace/modelName
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no limits to the number of models you can instantiate in your controller as long as you declare them above correctly.I think what you need is way to merge the result of all the models if that is so, then you have to use the [merge method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-merge), otherwise can you please clarify a little bit your question.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can retrieve them at one controller,

you're already halfway there, you should separate on different variable

```
public function index()
{
    $comms = CommentaireCritique::all() 
    $news = CommentaireNews::all()
    $dossier = CommentaireDossier::all()  
    $episodes = CommentaireEpisode::all()
    $series = CommentaireSerie::all()  
    $trailers = CommentaireTrailer::all()


    return view('admin.commentaires.index', compact('comms','news','dossier','episodes','series','trailers'));
}
```

if you want put them in one variable, you can use collection [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-merge)

Comment: I tried it but I'm not retrieving the data from all the tables. I think I'm gonna go with another database !

Comment: did you setup the model correctly ? are the value inside those 6 different tables exists ?

Comment: yes but I would like to call just one object in my blade to have just {{ $comms->email }} or {{ $comms->text }} and with this method I have to put individualy all the objects. I don't know if it's clear

Answer (score 0):

All of the results from `all()` function returns laravel collections. So use `concat()` function to concatenate all those into one collection

```php
public function index()
{
    $coms = CommentaireCritique::all()
        ->concat(CommentaireNews::all())
        ->concat(CommentaireDossier::all())
        ->concat(CommentaireEpisode::all())
        ->concat(CommentaireSerie::all())
        ->concat(CommentaireTrailer::all());

    return view('admin.commentaires.index', compact('comms'));
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, there was a syntax error. please note that the `arrow` when method calling instead of `dot`.  :) It was a mistake